# Comparison morphism between Čech and sheaf cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ a topological space (ie a scheme) and $E$ be
a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$. Now we can associate to
$X and E$ sheaf cohomology groups $H^i(X,E)$. For an explicit construction
choose an injective resolution

$$ 0 \to E \to I_0 \to I_1 \to I_2 \to ... $$

Then the sheaf cohomology groups are cohomology groups of the
chain complex

$$ 0 \to I_0(X) \to I_1(X) \to I_2(X) \to ...  $$

for global sections $I_j(X)$ of $I_j$. In some cases the
Čech cohomology gives a good approximation to sheaf cohomology
that is often useful for computations. If $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover
of $X$, then Čech cohomology $H^j(\mathcal{U}, E)$ is defined as
the cohomology of an explicit complex of abelian groups with $j$th group

$$  C^i(\mathcal{U}, E) = \prod_{i_0 < ... <i_j}E(U_{i_0} \cap ... \cap U_{i_j}) .$$

The cohomology groups $\check{H}^{j}(X,E)$ are defined as the
direct limit of the $H^i(U, E)$
over all open covers $U $ of $X$. In literature is often noted
that there is a comparison map

$$  \check{H}^{j}(X,E) \to   H^j(X,E)    $$

which in some nice situation is an isomorphism. But I haven't found
somewhere an explanation how this comparison map is
explicitely constructed. Could somebody give a sketch how the
construction works? Obviously it is sufficient to construct the maps $ H^j(\mathcal{U}, E)\to  H^j(X, E)$ and then push it to direct limit. How the last map is constructed?

Comment: What you want is the Cech-to-derived-functor spectral sequence. There's a fair bit of material on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=cech+to+derived) about this, and one place to go read the original material is Godement's book on sheaves.

Comment: IIRC you can construct a double complex by considering the (direct limit for all covers of) the Cech complex of each sheaf in the injective resolution. The trick is that this complex is exact for each injective (because filtered colimits are exact and an injective has vanishing Cech cohomology because [eg] it’s a direct factor of a flabby sheaf). Then you can “play” with the “grid”, by moving “along the diagonal” from the complex computing the Cech cohomology to the (orthogonal) one computing sheaf cohomology. There’s probably a cleaner way with spectral sequences if you know them.

Comment: @Mindlack: could you elaborate your argument on “play with the grid” by moving “along the diagonal” from the complex computing the Cech cohomology to the one computing sheaf cohomology. I can't follow you at this point, and it looks like an rather universally applicable interesting technique for handling cohomology of double complexes in certain "nice" situations like here for injective resolutions

Comment: Tbh that’s probably just a trick that is completely superseded by spectral sequences, but since I don’t really understand them yet… I’ll elaborate (you may want to draw the diagram). Consider the double complex $E^{i,j}$ such that the groups are $0$ if $i<-1$ or $j<-1$, $E^{i,j}=C^i(X,I_j)$ (in the Cech complex) with $C^{-1}(X,-)=H^0(X,-)$ and $I_{-1}$ is your original sheaf, so that $E^{\cdot,j}$ is exact for $j \geq 0$ and $E^{-2,j} \rightarrow E^{-1,j} \rightarrow E^{0,j} \rightarrow E^{1,j}$ is always exact. Let $K^{i,j}$ be the kernel of $E^{i,j} \rightarrow E^{i+1,j+1}$ (cont’d).

Comment: Let $B^{i,j}$ the sum of the images of all the arrows to $E^{i,j}$. The thing is to construct a map $K^{i,j}/B^{i,j} \rightarrow K^{i-1,j+1}/K^{i-1,j+1}$ for all $j \geq -1$ and $i \geq 0$ (?) by taking an element $x \in K^{i,j}$, considering its image $y \in E^{i,j+1}$ who has to come (by exactness) from some $z \in E^{i-1,j+1}$. (The quotients by the $B^{i,j}$ are just the technicalities to make the intermediary steps work). Anyway, by composing, you end up to a map $H_{Cech}(X)=K^{i,-1}/B \rightarrow K^{i-1,0}/B \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow K^{-1,i}/B=H^i_{sheaf}(X)$.

Comment: For the question in OP, the comparison morphism is simply constructed by the universal property of injective sheaves. There is a natural morphism from your Cêch complex to the injective complex. As others already explained, if the Cêch-to-derived spectral sequence has some good properties, then this morphism will be an isomorphism.

Comment: @hyyyyy: on which level do you consider the Čech complex? As a complex of abelian groups or it's sheaf version? The point is that if you use the trick I'm thinking about you want to constuct stepwise a morphism from $(j+1)$th member of this Čech complex to $(j+1)$th member of the injective resolution $I^{\bullet}$ inductively assuming that the morphism between $i$th ($i \le j$) members of these complexes are constructed. And then the $(j+1)$th morphism also exist due to injectivity of $I_{j+1}$.  Is this your idea?

Comment: @user7391733 I consider it as a sheaf of abelian groups. And yes, that is my idea of the construction.

Comment: @hyyyy: isn't there a little problem hidden? The sheaf-version
$\mathcal{ShC}^i(\mathcal{U}, E)$
you associate to $i$th Čech complex
$C^i(\mathcal{U}, E) = \prod_{i_0 < ... <i_j}E(U_{i_0} \cap ... \cap U_{i_j} )$
you construct as sheafification of presheaf
$V \mapsto C^i(\mathcal{U} \cap V, E) := \prod_{i_0 < ... <i_j}E(U_{i_0} \cap ... \cap U_{i_j} \cap V)$.
For this we obtain successively applying the 
injectivity of sheaves $\mathcal{I}^j$ a vertical map
of complexes $\mathcal{ShC}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{U}, E) \to
\mathcal{I}^{\bullet}$.

Comment: Next we should apply global 
section functor to this map and obtain a map
of complexes of abelian groups
$\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{U}, E)(X) \to
\mathcal{I}^{\bullet}(X)$ and take presumingly
the cohomology of these complexes. The problem is
why $(\mathcal{ShC}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{U}, E))(X)=
C^i(\mathcal{U}, E)$? In general there is 
no reason why the global sections of a 
presheaf should coincide with global sections of
it's sheafification. Do you know how to overcome this obstacle?

Comment: Finally, we want that the complex
$(\mathcal{ShC}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{U}, E))(X)$
is the same as 
$C^{\bullet}(\mathcal{U}, E)$ since we are 
intersted in comparison maps
$H^j(\mathcal{U}, E)\to  H^j(X, E)$, therefore we should assure that the complexes
$(\mathcal{ShC}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{U}, E))(X)$
and
$C^{\bullet}(\mathcal{U}, E)(X)$ are the same.

Comment: @user267839 Isn't $\mathcal{C}^\bullet (\mathcal{U},E)$ already a sheaf? It appears to be the product of the sheaves $V\mapsto E(U_{i_0,\cdots,i_j}\cap V)$, which are the pushforwards of the sheaf $E|U_{i_0,\cdots,i_j}$ under the inclusion $U_{i_0,\cdots,i_j}\to X$. This is in Hartshorne, Chapter III, lemma 4.1 and the preceding definition.